# updating a model attribute that will only change once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have a `subject` model with attributes including a `start_date` and `end_date` - as well as a `completed` boolean attribute.

In `subject.rb`, I have a method to find how many weeks are remaining for a given `subject`:

```
  def weeks_left
    time = (self.end_date.to_time - Date.today.to_time).round/1.week
    if time < 0
      "completed"
    elsif time < 1
      "less than 1 week"
    elsif time == 1
      "1 week"
    else
      "#{time} weeks" 
    end
  end
```

I want to tick the `completed` attribute if `self.weeks_left == "completed"` and the best way to do that seems like a call back, but I'm a bit unsure about using after_find - in general it seems like it would be too many queries, and indeed too big of a pain (especially after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808504/why-callbacks-for-the-after-find-and-after-initialize-events-is-to-define-them-a)) - but in this case, once a subject is complete, it's not going to change, so it seems useless to check it's status more than once - what's the best way to handle this?

Comment: why do you need an attribute for this? Just make a method which calculates this?

Comment: i'm going to be sorting this model by whether they're completed - so it's easier to do that via an attribute, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you make a scope for this?

```
scope :completed, ->{where("end_date <= ?", Time.now)}
```

and a method

```
def completed?
  self.weeks_left == "completed"
end
```

Comment: Scope sounds like a really good idea, thanks - why a method also?

Comment: Because then you can call the method on the object.. if you need it? if not, then drop it :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need ActiveRecord::Callbacks. You can see more information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) or on [rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

```
before_save :update_completed

def update_completed
  if (end_date_changed?)
    time = (self.end_date.to_time - Date.today.to_time).round/1.week
    self.complete = time < 0
  end
end
```

This way you update the complete flag whenever end_date changes and it would always be in sync.

However because this is a calculated value you could also not store it as an attribute and simply define a method to get it

```
def complete
  time = (self.end_date.to_time - Date.today.to_time).round/1.week
  return time < 0
end
```